# SQL code patterns mapped to Matlab operations on `table's`

Tags: sql, matlab, ms-access

I'm quite comfortable (and somewhat critically dependent) on Microsoft Access (SQL 92) code idioms patterns, including nested SELECTs, various JOINs, filtering, column ordering, and aliasing of columns and tables.

I'm starting to feebly finding my way around Matlab's equivalent operations on tables.

Other than the examples shown for the individual commands, is there a (possibly small) compendium of SQL code patterns and equivalent Matlab code?  In case it matters, I'm using Matlab 2015b.

Other than code patterns, I am also hoping to get savvy at issues like type conversion when applying aggregation operations on table records.  I've deliberately used `uint16` to contain the memory footprint of my table because I know the value range of the fields are limited.  Having never worried about basic type control before, however, I am only now discovering gotchas, like no automatic type promotion when the (possibly intermediate) results of an expression evaluation exceeds the range that is supported by the operand types.  I don't recall *ever* having to worry about this is SQL, but if there are any advised practices to handle or skirt these issues in Matlab, thanks for pointing me to them.

Comment: Would the person who voted this question down please say what can be done to improve it?  I doubt that I'm the only one wanting to ramp up quickly on Matlab's capabilities that are counterpart to SQL.  If such a ready compendium of examples exists, it would be a lot quicker than relying solely on the documentation.  I see the main purpose of the latter as as reference document, with examples of quite simple table operations compared to nested SQL constructs.

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess is that the breadth of your question is the reason for it.

Comment: You're probably right.  But that's the question.  It's asking for a lot, I admit, since it's the kind of knowledge that coalesces with time and user experience.  It's compilation awaits someone with the fortitude and altruism to undertake the task.  But I don't think it's unreasonable to ask about it.  I think it would be irresponsible *not* to look for something like a code pattern mapping as a start.

Comment: Hi @user36800, it has been long time since you asked this question. In the meanwhile, I created a Matlab script that probably provides what you are looking for. Take a look at it by visiting the following page: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68771-table-sql

Comment: Thanks, Tommaso. It is a phenomenal wrapper. Since I posted this question, however, I've gotten comfortable with the Matlab counterparts to SQL. They allow greater flexibility in blending procedural, vector/array, and relational operations. I want to live entirely in the world of Matlab code patterns. When I need the hyper-optimized SQL engines, I'll submit SQL code to an Access interface. But thanks. P.S. I may even store "functions" as queries in the Access DB. I can write them in native SQL and avoid the headache of handling their string representation in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables are the closest thing to a `SQL` dataset you can find in Matlab. The first thing you should do is to read [this official documentation page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html#d119e28052) very carefully, because it teaches you the basics for accessing and manipulating data in a table object.

Once it's done, you will be halfway to your goal. A few good examples and some training will finally make you reach the peak. Let's take this table as reference for the upcoming cheatsheet:

```
load patients; % Load default data...
patients = table(Age,Gender,Height,Weight); % Create the table...
```

**SELECT**

Basic `SELECT` statements can be performed using the accessing approaches shown in the official documentation.

```
SQL    => SELECT * FROM Patients
Matlab => patients

SQL    => SELECT Gender, Height FROM Patients
Matlab => patients(:,{'Gender' 'Height'})

SQL    => SELECT Gender, Age FROM Patients LIMIT 5
SQL    => SELECT TOP 5 Gender, Age FROM Patients
Matlab => patients(1:5,{'Gender' 'Age'})
```

Be careful with variable assignments when performing selections. If you assign the result of a selection to the variable that is being used for storing the dataset, then the original dataset is replaced and lost forever:

```
patients = table(Age,Gender,Height,Weight); % Dataset is created...
patients = patients(1:5,{'Gender' 'Age'}); % Dataset is replaced...
```

In order to avoid this, store the result of your selections into another variable, as follows:

```
patients = table(Age,Gender,Height,Weight); % Dataset is created...
patients_selection = patients(1:5,{'Gender' 'Age'}); % Dataset is not replaced...
```

Nested `SELECT` statements or `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...)` structures are just distinct selections performed on intermediate results (signally, variables that store the intermediate results).

**DISTINCT**

The `DISTINCT` clause for selections can be performed using the [unique](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function.

```
SQL    => SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Patients
Matlab => unique(patients)

SQL    => SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM Patients
Matlab => unique(patients(:,{'Gender'}))
```

**WHERE**

Filters applied by `WHERE` clauses are a little bit trickier to obtain. You must create logical indexers based on table columns, and use them to select the proper rows.

```
SQL    => SELECT Height FROM Patients WHERE Gender = 'Female'
Matlab => patients(strcmp(patients.Gender,'Female'),{'Height'})

SQL    => SELECT Weight FROM Patients WHERE Age >= 30
Matlab => patients(patients.Age >= 30,{'Weight'})

SQL    => SELECT Gender, Age, Weight FROM Patients WHERE (Gender = 'Male' AND Age >= 50) OR (Gender = 'Female' AND Age <= 50)
Matlab => idx = (strcmp(patients.Gender,'Male') & (patients.Age >= 50)) | (strcmp(patients.Gender,'Female') & (patients.Age <= 50));
          patients(idx,{'Gender' 'Age' 'Weight'})
```

**ORDER BY**

The `ORDER BY` statement equivalent is the [sortrows](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) function.

```
SQL    => SELECT * FROM Patients ORDER BY Height ASC, Weight DESC
Matlab => sortrows(patients,{'Height','Weight'},{'ascend','descend'})

SQL    => SELECT Height, Weight FROM Patients WHERE Gender = 'Female' ORDER BY Height ASC, Weight DESC
Matlab => sortrows(patients(strcmp(patients.Gender,'Female'),{'Height','Weight'}),{'Height','Weight'},{'ascend','descend'})
```

**GROUP BY**

Grouping statements can be achieved using the [findgroups](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) function, and data aggregation (for example `AVG` and `SUM`) can be performed using the [splitapply](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) function coupled with the former.

```
SQL    => SELECT Gender, SUM(Weight) AS 'TotalWeight' FROM Patients GROUP BY Gender
Matlab => [groups,Gender] = findgroups(patients.Gender);
          TotalWeight = splitapply(@sum,patients.Weight,groups);
          table(Gender,TotalWeight)

SQL    => SELECT Gender, Weight, AVG(Height) AS 'AverageHeight' FROM Patients GROUP BY Gender, Weight ORDER BY Gender ASC, Weight ASC, AverageHeight ASC
Matlab => patients40 = patients(patients.Age <= 40,:);
          [groups,Gender,Weight] = findgroups(patients40.Gender,patients40.Weight);
          AverageHeight = splitapply(@mean,patients40.Height,groups);
          sortrows(table(Gender,Weight,AverageHeight),{'Gender' 'Weight' 'AverageHeight'},{'ascend' 'ascend' 'ascend'})
```

**COUNT**

The total number of rows in a table can be retrieved using the [height](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/height.html) function.

```
SQL    => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patients
Matlab => height(patients)

SQL    => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patients WHERE Gender = 'Male'
Matlab => height(patients(strcmp(patients.Gender,'Male'),:))
```

**JOINS, INTERSECTIONS & UNIONS**

Joins can be performed using the built-in [join](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.join.html), [innerjoin](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html) and [outerjoin](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html) functions. Intersections and unions can be performed, respectively, using the [intersect](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btxem7d-4) function and the [union](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html) function. Unions can also be performed by concatenating two tables (provided they have the same number of columns and the same column names) using the following syntax:

```
MyTable3 = [MyTable1; MyTable2];
```

The examples provided in the links should be easy enough to understand and reproduce.

**INSERT, DELETE & UPDATE**

In [this official documentation page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-rows.html) you should find all what you need in order to perform insertions and deletion of rows in tables. Insertions can be quickly performed using concatenation:

```
SQL    => INSERT INTO Patients (Age,Gender,Height,Weight) VALUES (32,'Female',182,72)
Matlab => patients = [patients; {32,'Female',182,72}]
```

While deletions are performed on a row-wise indexing basis:

```
SQL    => DELETE FROM Patients WHERE Gender = 'Male' AND Age <= 35
Matlab => idx = strcmp(patients.Gender,'Male') & (patients.Age <= 35);
          patients(idx,:) = []
```

Updates are a little bit different to handle. You can use a direct column access together with a predefined indexing in order to perform them easily:

```
SQL    => UPDATE Patients SET Age = 50, Hight = 175, Weight = 70 WHERE Gender = 'Male'
Matlab => idx = strcmp(patients.Gender,'Male');
          patients.Age(idx) = 40;
          patients.Height(idx) = 175;
          patients.Weight(idx) = 70;
```

**EDIT**

A few days ago, I created a Matlab script that probably provides what you are looking for. Basically, it's a SQL wrapper around Matlab tables. Take a look at it by visiting the following page:

http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68771-table-sql

Comment: Thanks, Tommaso.  I was going to ask whether you ever considered keeping a website up with the above examples.  These days, however, Stack Overflow is the way to go.  Your examples confirm to me that Matlab code has to do more bookkeeping of boolean indexing vectors and intermediate tables.  Because of this, I was tempted to ferret around to figure out programmatic creation of an Access database, exporting tables, using real SQL, then importing the results.

Comment: But that's a lot of extra cruft just to be able to access the more streamline SQL code and the hyperoptimization of relational database engines.  I think I'll bite the bullet and get close and personal with the Matlab code patterns.  Again, many thanks for what looks like the significant effort that you put into answering my question.